# Laravel: Retrieve image from database in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a form where you can submit images. It checks it it is an an image and it saves it into the database. My issue is how do i view it? I don't know the url for the image.

The ImageController:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
         'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
        $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');
        $save = new Image;
        $save->name = $name;
        $save->path = $path;
        $save->save();
        return redirect('/')->with('mssg', 'Image Has been uploaded');
    }
```

Form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="wrapper adoption-details">
            <h1>Adoption for {{ $animal->name }}</h1>
            <img src="{{ asset('/image') }}" />
            <p>Name: {{ $animal->name }} </br>
               DoB: {{ $animal->dob }} </br>
               Availability: {{ $animal->available }} </br>
               Description: {{ $animal->description }} </br></p>
            
            <form name="image-upload" id="image-upload" method="post" action="{{url('upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 @csrf
        <div>
          <label for="choose">Please Select Image To Upload:</label>
          <input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="@error('image') is-invalid @enderror form-control">
          @error('image')
              <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
          @enderror
        </div>
        <button type="submit" Submit="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    <a href="/animals" class="back">Back to all requests</a>
@endsection
```

What would be the `<img src="{{ asset('/image') }}" />` be? The path of the image is **storage/app/public/images/**.

Comment: Read this section of the Laravel documents: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads and use this approach. As you can see in `config/filesystems.php` there are several disks defined by default. The one you are looking for is `public`. Retrieving the file would be `{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($image->path); ` directly into the img->src.The reason why `public` exists is because it's a bad idea to upload files directly into the public folder. Don't forget to create the symbolic link on both test and production `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @DimitriMostrey, I don't have a config/filesystem.php?

Comment: On a Laravel setup? It's one of the core conig files. It automatically comes with a fresh laravel installation. Very strange indeed. This file shows your 'disks' or places you can put and retrieve files. This could also be Amazon S3 or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your disk in `config/filesystem.php`. Something like this:

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

In `.env` file select default disk. You can configure many disks.
Then save the path in database in column image (like a varchar) and add this column to SQL query.
Remeber to add command `php artisan storage:link` then in blade use `<img src="{{ Storage::url($animal->image) }}" />`

Laravel documentation is very helpful. Read this [Laravel Docs - Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#introduction). I think you will find answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer, except you may have to define the correct disk. The default is `local` and not `public`, hence `<img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($animal->image) }}" />`, unless of course, @Alia sets the default to `public`.

Comment: @Isek, I don't have a config/filesystem.php?

Comment: @Alia which laravel version are you using? Laravel 7 or 8?

Comment: @HassaanAli, 8.36.0